# I use this methed to update my data but it doesn't updating any thing also doesn't show any mistake

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitDB');

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
    rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 10
  },
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit ({
  rating: 10,
  review: "Peaches are so yummy!" 
});

fruit.save();


Fruit.updateOne({_id: "64489b61855d2950c7a678ab"}, {name: "Peach"});
```

Comment: How would you know what the ID is? And isn't `save` async? Or are you **only** trying to update a known `Fruit` w/ that ID and the creation code isn't relevant?

Comment: on hyper it gives me this id by default

Comment: I don't know what "hyper" means in this context. That said: so your question is why isn't the fruit w/ this ID being modified? How are you checking it for changes?

Comment: I check by using this program :   https://hyper.is/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That’s a terminal. How are you looking at the data?

Comment: I use this way to show data in the terminal : 1-   I run the node app.js in terminal   2- I open another window in terminal and I write this :  mongo shell - show dbs - use fruitDB - show collections - db.fruits.find()

Comment: this is how I check the data --- my question is: I want to make an update on my data but no changes happen so I want to know where is the problem. the code I use for that is :  Fruit.updateOne({_id: "64489b61855d2950c7a678ab"}, {name: "Peach"});

Comment: If you do a `Fruit.findOne({_id: "64489b61855d2950c7a678ab"})` do you see any output? It might be that the `_id` you're updating doesn't exist so it doesn't update anything.

Comment: Actually there is no output.  is there another method I can use to update the data.  I mean instead of _id